# Django Admin showing thumbnail of foreign key's imagefield in inline form

Tags: django, django-admin, thumbnails, imagefield

I have a simple structure, with a Product model, and AppMedia model and a ProductMedia join table.

Product (has many) ProductMedia

ProductMedia (has one) AppMedia

What I would really like is to see the thumbnail for AppMedia's media field in an inline form in Product.

e.g. edit Product in Django admin, shows a StackedInline form. This contains (at present) a drop down (select) of all AppMedia.

What I need is the thumbnail.

Any help appreciated.

I am certain this isn't difficult, but I'm struggling. It's quite straight forward to put a thumbnail in for the AppMedia form (which is where the media ImageField resides), but not for the ProductMedia form which is using AppMedia as a ForeignKey.

Basic Models...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class AppMedia(models.Model):
    media           = models.ImageField(upload_to=appmedia_upload_to) #appmedia_upload_to defined elsewhere)

class ProductMedia(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    media           = models.ForeignKey(AppMedia)
    media_order     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product         = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

The AppMedia is shared in this way to stop multiple uploads of the same file and also to store extra meta-data (not displayed here) with the image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I hope at least one of my attempts will be usable for your case:

My first attempt to solve this problem (without overriding `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`) was to:

- set `form` property in inline admin where thumbnail should be displayed
- add another field into given form class with widget, which will display a thumbnail

However I abandoned this solution because I think I have to inject data about thumbnail into given field in form's constructor and I don't consider it a nice solution.

My next solution was to use `MultiWidget` for some field. In this case I don't need to add another field to form and I'll have data required to display thumbnail in widget without any need to inject them in constructor.

```
class ThumbnailMultiWidget(MultiWidget):

   def decompress(self, value):
       #has to be overriden
       return [None,None]


class ThumbnailWidget(Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
       #not quite sure what is in `value`, I've not been so far
       return '<img src="%s"/>' % value.url


class PhotoInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhotoInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        wdgts = [self.fields['media'].widget, ThumbnailWidget()]
        self.fields['media'].widget = ThumbnailMultiWidget(widgets=wdgts)


    class Meta:
        model = RecipePhoto
```

But I abandoned this solution as well, because I found out, that there's actually an instance's representation in `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` (which is widget I use) with all data I need to show the thumbnail. And that is my final solution:

So because my inline items have `raw_id_field` for choosing an inline record, I could simply override method `label_for_value` in  `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`, which is used to represent existing inline record. Usually it's `__unicode__` (I think). I inherited `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` and overriden this method to show image thumbnail:

```
class PhotoForeignKeyRawIdWidget(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget):

    def label_for_value(self, value):
        key = self.rel.get_related_field().name
        try:
            obj = self.rel.to._default_manager.using(self.db).get(**{key: value})
        except (ValueError, self.rel.to.DoesNotExist):
            return ''
        else:
            """
            there's utilized sorl.thumbnail, but you can return st like this:
            <img src='%s' /> % obj.media.url
            """
            return Template("""{% load thumbnail %}
            {% thumbnail image.image "120x120" crop="center" as one %}
                <img src="{{ one.url }}" />
            {% endthumbnail %}""").render(Context({
                'image': obj
            }))


class AppMediaInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AppMedia
    extra = 1

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'media':
            db = kwargs.get('using')
            kwargs['widget'] = PhotoForeignKeyRawIdWidget(db_field.rel, self.admin_site, using=db)
        return super(AppMediaInlineAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the related_name parameter for foreign keys, which will allow you to access the ProductMedia in reverse, i.e. if you change the ProductMedia model to:

```
class ProductMedia(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    media           = models.ForeignKey(AppMedia)
    media_order     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product         = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='media')
```

You could access the media object in Product model, which will allow you to put it in your admin in-line form. i.e you would have (for an easier explanation I've put the ImageField in ProductMedia):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name             = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def admin_image(self):
        return '<img src="%s"/>' % (self.media.all()[0].image.url)
    admin_image.allow_tags = True

class ProductMedia(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=appmedia_upload_to) #appmedia_upload_to defined elsewhere)
    media_order     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product         = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='media')
```

Then in your admin.py put:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'admin_image')

admin.site.register(models.Product, ProductAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Hope I understood your question correctly and that helped. Also the code isn't tested but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.

Comment: This solution makes the model tightly coupled with the admin app.